# RxJava и Retrofit асинхронные запросы и запрос на основа результата другого

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava, rxandroid

Я новичок в программирование. Возник вопрос, у меня есть к примеру  4 запроса. Которые возвращают разные данные.

```
    @GET("/api1/")
Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> getYkrepClanRx(@Query("clan_id") String clan_id, @Query("application_id") String application_id);

@GET("/api2/")
Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> getDannieClanRx(@Query("clan_id") String clan_id, @Query("application_id") String application_id);

@GET("/api3/")
Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>>getPersonallyDannieClanPlayerRx(@Query("account_id") String account_id, @Query("application_id") String application_id);

   @GET("/api4/")
    Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>>getPersonallyDannieClanPlayerRx2(@Query("account_id") String account_id, @Query("application_id") String application_id);
```

И вот у меня стоит задача.  Второй запрос зависит от результата первого. Как видно ниже это реализовано, возможно как-то лучше сделать, но нашел такое решение на форуме. Нужно добавить еще 2 асинхронных запроса. И чтоб я мог обработать их результаты(они возвращают разные объекты, по разному обработать). Как это можно сделать?

```
    final ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService("ru");

    Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> firstFlowable = api.getDannieClanRx("179746", application_id);

    Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable = firstFlowable
            .flatMap(new Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>>>() {
                @Override
                public Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>> apply(Response<ResponseBody> response) throws Exception {
                   // Log.d("TAG_DANNIE", response.body().string());
                    list = response.body().string();
                    clan_dannie.setDannieClanNew(generateDannieClan.generateDannieClan(list, "179746"));
                    Log.e("Tag", list);
                    return api.getPersonallyDannieClanPlayerRx(clan_dannie.getDannieClanNew().getMembersString2(), application_id);
                }
            });


    flowable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {

                    s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                    //Прилетел ответ
                    try {
                        Log.e("TAG",responseBodyResponse.body().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Я мало пока не полностью понимаю как это работает. Еще вчера я использовал `AnsyTask`, но почитал немного статей, и понял что нужно переделать под `Retrofit` и `RxJava`.

Мой `build.exe`

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
```

Мой `client`

```
  private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(String lz) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL + lz)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }



    /**
     * Get API Service
     *
     * @return API Service
     */
    public static ApiService getApiService(String lz) {
        return getRetrofitInstance(lz).create(ApiService.class);
    }
```

На данный момент сделал таким способом. Это правильно? Или копать другой способ?

```
            final ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService("ru");


        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> firstFlowable = api.getDannieClanRx(clan_id, application_id);

        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable = firstFlowable
                .flatMap(new Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>> apply(Response<ResponseBody> response) throws Exception {
                        // Log.d("TAG_DANNIE", response.body().string());
                        list = response.body().string();
                        clan_dannie.setDannieClanNew(generateDannieClan.generateDannieClan(list, clan_id));
                        Log.e("Tag", list);
                        return api.getPersonallyDannieClanPlayerRx(clan_dannie.getDannieClanNew().getMembersString2(), application_id);
                    }
                });

        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable2 = flowable
                .mergeWith(api.getRatingClanRx(clan_id, application_id));

        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable3 = flowable2
                .mergeWith(api.getYkrepClanRx(clan_id, application_id));

        flowable3
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                        //Показать диалог
                        dialog.show();
                        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                        //Прилетел ответ
                        try {
                            Log.e("URL", String.valueOf(responseBodyResponse.raw().request().url()));
                            Log.e("TAG", responseBodyResponse.body().string());
                            hashMap.put(String.valueOf(responseBodyResponse.raw().request().url()), responseBodyResponse.body().string());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        //Ошибка
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        //Убрать диалог
                        //Dismiss Dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: немного не понял вопрос, но что вам мешает в `onComplete` первого вызова делать второй?

Comment: rjhdby, добавил обновленную версию. Это работает. Но с точки программирования, это правильно? Или искать дальше решения

Comment: Собственно основная идея Rx в том и состоит, что вы оперируете потоками событий. Так что с точки зрения Rx - все правильно. Другое дело, что существуют и другие идеологии - тут уж что кому ближе